# jQuery show/hide options if button selected

Tags: javascript, button, html-select, show-hide

How I can change SELECT form to TAB from.

I have this code:

```js
var $clonedOpts = $("#layout_select").children().clone();

$("#column_select").change(function() { 
  var $layOpts = $clonedOpts.clone().filter('[value^=' + $(this).val() + ']');
  $("#layout_select").html($layOpts);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
  <option value="col1">1 column</option>
  <option value="col2">2 column</option>
  <option value="col3">3 column</option>
</select>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">
  <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
  <option value="col1">none</option>

  <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
  <option value="col2_ms">layout 1</option>
  <option value="col2_sm">layout 2</option>

  <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
  <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
  <option value="col3_ssm" selected="selected">layout 4</option>
  <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
</select>
```

I want change this code (select options):

```html
<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
  <option value="col1">1 column</option>
  <option value="col2">2 column</option>
  <option value="col3">3 column</option>
</select>
```

To this code (TAB forms):

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button>TAB1</button>
  <button>TAB2</button>
  <button>TAB3</button>
</div>
```

What I should change in javascript?

Comment: what do you exactly want? Your requirement is not clear. please explain in detail.

Comment: what's with select option values?? values will be lost if you convert to tabs, you need to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-` attribute to attach values on button

And change event to `click`

```js
var $clonedOpts = $("#layout_select").children().clone();

$(".tab button").click(function() { 
  var $layOpts = $clonedOpts.clone().filter('[value^=' + $(this).data("val") + ']');
  $("#layout_select").html($layOpts);
});
$(".tab button").eq(0).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <button data-val="col1">TAB1</button>
  <button data-val="col2">TAB2</button>
  <button data-val="col3">TAB3</button>
</div>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">
  <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
  <option value="col1">none</option>

  <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
  <option value="col2_ms">layout 1</option>
  <option value="col2_sm">layout 2</option>

  <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
  <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
  <option value="col3_ssm" selected="selected">layout 4</option>
  <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Dear Ritesh,
Thank you for your help, could you can help me more?

How I can set as default choosed TAB1?

Comment: @PauliusRutkauskas just click on first button: `$(".tab button").eq(0).click();`. Answer updated

Comment: Maybe you can help me add "Not selected" option in this script. But "Not selected" value should be empty. Added script link to JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/beauto/7ekLd3zf/1/)

Comment: I think this cannot be done with empty values. You should add values like, `col1_` , `col2_ `,`col3_` for empty values